# javascript (prototype) if element does not have attribute

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

in prototype I have this 'if' statement that works fine:

```
if(parentForm.hasAttribute('action')){
 console.log('hello world')
}
```

However, how do I turn this into a 'if parentForm DOES NOT have attribute action' statement?

Many thanks,
Adi.

Answer (score 1):

Simply negate the conditional using the [logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_%28!%29);

```
if(!parentForm.hasAttribute('action')){
 console.log('hello world')
}
```